# What Drupal module that usually handle this kind of variable format [field_box_image_fid]

Tags: views

Hi guys I badly need your help. I am new at Drupal, our site is doing fine a while ago. Until my supervisor told me to modify a job posting posted from our drupal site.

I cannot find the source page which I need to edit, so I use [THEME DEVELOPER](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) plugin to find out if the content I am searching is can be found in .TPL files. Upon activating the THEME DEVELOPER theme, theres a prompt that told me that activating this module might cause problem. I ignore the warning message and thought that if an error occur it can be solve immediately upon disabling the module.

I already disabled the THEME DEVELOPER module, but our site is completely malfunctioning. It displays  [field_box_image_fid] [field_box_image_fid] [field_box_image_fid] [field_box_image_fid] [field_box_image_fid] [field_box_image_fid] [field_box_image_fid] [field_box_image_fid] from our site homepage.

I don't know what modules I need to turn off or turn on to put this down.

NOTE: We are using DRUPAL 6

Comment: Did you change any of the tpl files? Did you clear the cache?

Comment: @pontus-nilsson yes sir I already clear cache. I noticed that upon activating the THEME DEVELOPER module, it DEACTIVATES some of my modules. I don't know which from the dozen modules here I need to turn on to restore our site

Comment: One guess is a module that enables media to be used in a text field (text format). Could it be that media_wysiwyg for example has been disabled?

Comment: I'd be suspecting [Token Filter](https://drupal.org/project/token_filter)

Comment: I would do as @Clive suggests and enable Token Filter module

Comment: For what it's worth, installing theme developer **doesn't** disable or uninstall any other modules. That would be nuts. The other modules have been disabled by another method, or you have some rogue custom/contrib modules doing stuff they're not supposed to. If that's the case, disable them methodically until you find the culprit